# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'rowsdata' of undefined

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, typescript, angular, electron

I am stuck at some point working with angular 2 with node js. below is my code. It couldn't set rows(variable) to `this.rowsdata` (variable).
I think the reason behind is that node Js uses asynchronous call. May be that's why this.rows data get undefined for rows.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/node/node.d.ts" />
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { OnInit } from 'angular2/core';

declare var module : any;
declare var jQuery : any;
var rowsdata : any[] = [];
// self = this;
interface ROWS {
name : string,
current_balance : number
}

@Component({
selector : 'portfolioList',
templateUrl : '../app/view/portfoliolist.html',
moduleId : module.id
})

export class PortfolioList implements OnInit {
 // self : any = this;

constructor() {
 // var self : this;
}

ngOnInit(): any {
 this.showdata();
 // console.log(this.rowsdata);
}

showdata() {
 console.log("called");
 var portfolioList = require('../app/api/showPortfolio.js');
 portfolioList.showPortfolio(function(err:any, rows:any) {
   console.log(rows);
   // self.rowsdata = rows;
   this.rowsdata = rows;
 });

 // console.log(self.rowsdata);

 console.log(rowsdata);
 }
}
```

here is the showPortfolio function

```
    exports.showPortfolio = function(callback) { 
db.all(squel .select() 
.from("portfolios") 
.field("name") 
.field("current_balance") .toString() , function(err, rows) {      callback(null, rows) }); 
}
```

Comment: `console.log(this)` before setting rowsdata. it should print 'undefined'. so you can't set a property of an undefined object. that's the message

Comment: i did not write `console.log(this)` to anywhere in the program. i want to set rows which is array of object to rowsdata. So i can use rowsdata in *ngFor in angular2 html template. Hope you understand.

Comment: i know you dont, i just told you to do it so as to see the error. basarat gave the answer which fixes the problem. fat arrows is the solution in order to reference `this` inside the function

Comment: I tried whatever he suggest me. Still getting same error. I think the reason why I am getting this is because node Js uses asynchronous call to function. so before getting the result it will execute the line `this.rowsdata = rows` because of this it gets nothing in rows. so it throws the error of undefined.

Comment: `showdata() {
 console.log("called");
 var portfolioList = require('../app/api/showPortfolio.js');
 portfolioList.showPortfolio(function(err:any, rows:any) {
   console.log(rows);
   // self.rowsdata = rows;
   this.rowsdata = rows;
 });

 // console.log(self.rowsdata);

 console.log(rowsdata);
 }
}`

Comment: ok did you try displaying the data with async pipe? i dont know how you manipulate your data but `| asyc` is for this reason.

Comment: I just want to display my rows data to html table. i uses angular 2 as a front end with typescript.. I don't know about `| asyc`.

Comment: google async pipe for angular 2 and let me know if this works for you

Comment: Nope. Obviously as the the value is not set to rowsdata. We can not get rowsdata in angular 2 html template.

Comment: I am really in a bad situation where i can not proceed further. Stuck here from 2 days. Just can't render rowsdata to angular 2 *ngFor.

Comment: it is set asynchronously, that's the meaning of async. do you have a github project for that so as to clone and test it locally?

Comment: we have but its private repo. I am an employee of the company. so can't send you github link.

Comment: ok so not much to do after this point. i cannot think of sth else.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your code :

```
portfolioList.showPortfolio(function(err:any, rows:any) {
```

Change this to a fat arrow:

```
portfolioList.showPortfolio((err:any, rows:any) => {
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: Are you sure? Also change `showdata() {` to `showdata = () => {` this is mentioned in the arrow function docs as well 

Comment: showdata = () => {
        console.log("called");

        portfolioList.showPortfolio((err:any, rows:any) => {
            // console.log(rows);
            // self.rowsdata = rows;
            this.rowsdata = rows;});

        // console.log(self.rowsdata);

        console.log(this.rowsdata);
      }

Comment: see the above code. i changed. sorry for improper formatting.

Comment: It will be a big help. If you solve my problem. I stuck here since two days.

Comment: Hello please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i cant post a comment with all this code, so i post an answer.
it should work like this. i've put some extra logs.

```
showdata() {
 console.log("called");
 var _this = this;
 console.log(_this);
 var portfolioList = require('../app/api/showPortfolio.js');
 portfolioList.showPortfolio(function(err:any, rows:any) {
   console.log(rows);
   console.log(_this);
   _this.rowsdata = rows;
 });

 // console.log(self.rowsdata);

 console.log(rowsdata);
 }
}
```

Comment: i'm posting an answer the "old-fashioned" way but i'm pretty sure basarat's solution works.

Comment: Still not getting the rows in rowsdata which is in last `console.log(rowsdata)`. I am shocked because when i just print first console.log(_this) first one i get the actual expected value but at last could not set rows to rowsdata.

Comment: Ok but that's one step further to solution. you dont get the `Cannot set property 'rowsdata' of undefined` error that your title says!

Comment: what is the definition of showPortfolio function? you dont have it in your question

Comment: yeah. but still in rowsdata variable. It is undefined.

Comment: Its just a database query.

`exports.showPortfolio = function(callback) {
   db.all(squel
          .select()
          .from("portfolios")
          .field("name")
          .field("current_balance")
          .toString()
        , function(err, rows) {
            callback(null, rows)
        });
}`